# Stopping system V runlevel compatibility - Stuck on logon screen

Tags: wireless, drivers, virtualbox, login-screen

My wireless stopped working suddenly and I tried to reinstall the driver. I think that I installed the wrong one and after rebooting I am stuck on Ubuntu login screen.
When I try to login Ubuntu blinks with black screen with the message:

`Stopping system V runlevel compatibility.`

After that it returns to the login screen.
`lspci` shows me WiFi driver RTL8191SEvB.

**I installed the RTL8187L driver when the problem appeared.

I tried to blacklist all kinds of RTL drivers but Ubuntu again and again shows me RTL8191SEvB.

Wireless card is working, I try it on Win.

This is the output I get when I try to login:

- Stopping save kernel messages
- Starting CUPS printing spooler/servers
- Starting VirutalBox kernel modules
- Starting bluetooth
- (STAR is a yellow color) PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions
  saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned 
  *checking battery state
- Stopping system V runlevel compatibility.

---

/etc/modules/

lp
rtc
coretemp

---

lsmod | grep rt

parport_pc  36962   0
parport  46562  3   parport_pc,ppdev,lp

---

blacklisted
(as I said I try all kind rtl drivers, but I try with with all commented also, same thing)

blacklist rtl8192se
blacklist rtl8192ce
blacklist rtl8192de
blacklist rtl8187L
blacklist rtl8187
blacklist rtlwifi

---

Kernel WARN:
[ 23.198960] mei: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned
Kernel ERROR
[ 1.077841] PCI0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_ERROR), returned control mask: 0x1d
[ 23.255556] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

Comment: You may find this thread interesting.http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1977519

Comment: @ElderGeek OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years, 2+ years before you comment posted 3+ years ago and unlikely to respond to it. Additionally this is about 12.04 which is EOL so I'm voting to close as `not reproducible`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Agreed on all points. joining you in this effort.